# chrome extension: Scripting pdf UI

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome displays content type pdfs into a dom like this:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38); height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin"
src="http://che.org.il/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/pdf-sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="3">
</body></html>
```

What is the easiest way to access the interior UI of the embed? Separately, is Chrome CRI able to do this?

(Apparently native Ctrl-F works, so there had got to be a way.)

Comment: The embedded object is handled by a native plugin so there's no way to run custom code within. You can reassemble resources.pak locally, though, and replace the shipped code with your own :-) The plugin runs a built-in chrome extension for its UI written in js.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Any idea if they're already working on exposing the UI? Or is it triaged to the back and not available at least for the next 10 yrs?

Comment: I see no reason for them to expose it. They don't expose any of the built-in UI.